# JavaScript JSON compare

Tags: javascript, json

There are two JSON `var` (JSON.parse'd already)

`var acc` http://pastebin.com/7DyfFzTx

`var sit` http://pastebin.com/vnZiVaDx

My objective is to loop each `var` to compare `acc.items.site_name` with `sit.items.main_site.name` to see if they are equal. If they are equal, then I need to store `sit.items.main_site.site_url` in a variable. I am using this code:

```
for(i=0; i < acc.items.length;i++)
{
  aname = acc.items[i].site_name;
  for(i=0; i < sit.items.length;i++)
    {
     sname = sit.items[i].main_site.name;
     if (aname == sname)
     alert("same "+aname);
    }
}
```

But the `alert` only logs "same Physics" . "Physics" is the first object in `acc.items`. This means that the loop is only comparing first `acc.items` but how do I make it compare the second and further on objects (e.g. "TeX - LaTeX")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the same variable for the inner and outer loop.

Give the second `for` loop a different variable name than `i`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you can start by using a different control variable for the outer and inner loops. :)

Also, notice how you are running through every element of the second object each time you consider an element in the first object- that doesn't seem like what you want to do.

Try reviewing this posting for a more modular method:

http://jsperf.com/recursive-vs-json-object-comparison